# Multiple observers of a MutableProperty in RAC3

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I have a "DataManager" singleton class that handles state for my app using RAC3.  It contains multiple `MutableProperty`s that I start and observe in various locations.

I would like to have my DataManager start or create a signal that I can observe in any view controller using my DataManager singleton, using `observe()` rather than `start()` etc.  But I am stuck and am not sure how to initialize this signal in my DataManager.  I've tried defining a property like

```
let documentUpdateSignal: Signal<Int,NSError>

let remainingDocuments = MutableProperty<Int>(0)
```

and then trying to start it with my mutable property's producer on init
something like

```
override init() {
  documentUpdateSignal = remainingDocuments.producer.start(next: {
    docs in
    println("doc count \(docs)")
  })
  super.init()
}
```

But this doesn't work since it doesn't return a `Signal<Int,NSError>`

I've also attempted to create a method that returns a Signal without much luck, rather than a property... like this even though it didn't seem quite right.

```
func updateSignal() -> Signal<Int, NSError> {
  return remainingDocuments.producer
}
```

Would love help
Thanks so much!

Comment: I have a feeling this is where `startWithSignal` comes into play, though I'm having trouble finding an example of how to use this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably worked this out by now:

```
var documentUpdateSignal: Signal<Int, NoError>?

....

remainingDocuments.producer.startWithSignal { 
            (var signal: Signal<Int, NoError>, var disposable : Disposable) -> () in
            self.documentUpdateSignal = signal
        }
```

I'm not sure that you'll be able to call `startWithSignal` from within your class' `init()` though, as `self` isn't available for capture by the block until `super`'s init is called. Given that, I've assumed `documentUpdateSignal` is optional.

Note that I've also changed the declaration of `documentUpdateSignal` from using `NSError` to `NoError` to suit `MutableProperty`'s producer's signature.

You can then observe the signal from elsewhere using:

```
self.documentUpdateSignal?.observe(next: { 
                (var value: Int) in
                println("Mutable property = \(value)")
            }
        )
```

Comment: Works as expected.  Thanks!